# Why is this question closed and what can I do to get it reopened?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I just don't think [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151757/what-are-the-constraints-on-using-odbc-to-connect-to-a-excel-database-xls) is unclear. Could anyone give concrete/detailed reason for its closure? And how can I modify it to get it reopened?

Comment: Purged the comments because of flags and the fact that they dove into arguments.  If you have an answer, post it.  If you want to complain about what another user does; flag their action for moderator attention.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - all sound advice, until the flag is declined and you're referred back to this question/meta in the flag message =/

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more readable and understandable, perhaps some of you would like to take a look at it.

Comment: @azulflame How does that improve the question? The wording is different but the problems are still the same.

Comment: If you look, It was closed 3 times: once for being more or less too vague, and twice after someone else editing it to remove the actual question the OP was asking. I simply reworded the question, restoring it to ask what the OP was asking.

Comment: @azulflame You essentially performed a rollback to the problematic question we have been discussing here. Exactly the form that caused it to be closed in the first place. While we had our arguments about Geochet's edits (causing some of the comments George refers to above) the edit you made IMHO doesn't get it any closer to being reopened.

Comment: @azul: My edit is what got it reopened the first time. You should really understand the issue before seeking to 'fix it'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question you asked is not all that unclear. At least not from a comprehensibility point of view. That is not the problem IMHO, though I'm not really familiar with the subject.

I should have said "questions" though. Plural. The first problem I see is that you're asking 3  questions to start off with. Ideally you should ask a single question per question. Asking multiple questions in one go is problematic with respect to answering them.

Then in your fourth and final question, you ask for a list of constraints, should there be any. Such list-of questions are also a poor fit for the Q&A. Where does the list end? We certainly don't want a whole host of different answers, each one piling on another constraint they have found.

And "I Googled but found inadequate information" does not narrow things down either. What did you find? Anything? Nothing? Just what you stated? It doesn't help your question along.

And with the note that I'm not familiar on the topic (so I might be utterly wrong on this one): The whole question gives me the sneaking suspicion that the answer might well be of the form "RTFM". As in, you might want to Google a bit harder or read the relevant documentation. I can't back this up, but I would not be surprised if that's part of why your question was not well received.

Comment: I mentioned that "I googled and found insufficient infomation", so I need someone who have done some (maybe original) research on this specific topic. Well as for "RTFM", IMHO there're QUITE A FEW questions asked on stackoverflow can fit in the "RTFM" category. I see no point in closing all of these questions.

Comment: That you found quite a few other questions which fit the RTFM category does not imply that your question is good. Perhaps they should have been closed as well and have slipped through the cracks. So that argument doesn't really work. I'm only trying to help you figure out what the problem might be and what you might want to address. For all I care you don't do anything with the information and just flag for moderator attention. But I would not suggest that approach.

Comment: Nonetheless, I partly agree with you on the first problem you pointed out. But I think the list of questions all fit in the single title "What are the constraints on using ODBC to connect to a Excel Database(*.xls)", they just serve as further clarification of the issue.

Comment: If that is the question you want to ask, then you're running into the "list of"-type anyway. Which is a problematic question form. In any case, it seems to have been reopened now. I don't agree, but there you go.

Comment: Well thanks for your suggestions anyway, next time I'll try to ask single question per question.

Comment: @turner Why not just edit the current question to have a single question? Hell, you could just rollback to my edit and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Ask a question that people can understand. See the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

With your reputation of 87 you can't vote to reopen the question. I recommend to first [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get reputation. To be able to vote for reopening your own question  requires 250 reputation.

Comment: Actually I have a reputation of 87 on the stackoverflow site

Comment: @Turner Thanks, corrected that.

Comment: @Tichodroma Voting to reopen or close your own questions requires a reputation of 250.

Comment: @Bart Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes ?

Comment: Nope. In the FAQ under "What is reputation" it states: *"250 Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions"*.

Comment: @Bart Thanks. Looks like the reputation description is incomplete in that point.

Comment: @Tichodroma IMHO, the question which I posted is GOOD, at least NOT BAD. Do you mean that the question cannot be understood? Well it may needs some clarification but overall it's totally intelligible.

Comment: Ah, I see a similar statement on the privileges page: "You may also cast a close or reopen vote on your questions.".

Comment: "I googled but fould inadequate infomation." -- Totally intelligible.